# jqgrid get all grids column names

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

Is there a way to get all of the grid's column names?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can get the column names with

```
var columnNames = $("#list")[0].p.colNames;
```

or

```
var columnNames = $("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam','colNames');
```

The only small problem is that the array `columnNames` will contain up to three empty first elements in case of you use `rownumbers:true`, `multiselect:true` or `subGrid:true` parameters. This parameters to follow to inserting in the `colModel` additional columns with the names `'rn'`, `'cb'` or `'subgrid'`. So you can either just ignore the first empty elements of `columnNames` or look additionally in the `colModel` (`$("#list")[0].p.colModel` or `$("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam','colModel')`). The `colModel` and `colNames` arrays has the same length and the `colModel[i].name` can be used to examine whether `colNames[i]` is the name of "real" column or an additional column added because of the usage one from the tree above mention parameters.

Comment: @FastTrack: You are welcome! I am glad to know that I could help you.

Comment: I am using this function and splice the columnNames to get rid of the first checkbox column. It seems to affect the actual grids colNames though...any ideas why? 
I posted a question here about it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25558700/jqgridgetgridparam-colnames-odd-behavior

Comment: @Oleg would this give the updated column order in case the user has reordered the columns? and would same be true for getting colModel ?

Comment: @Harshit: Yes. `getGridParam` can be used to get internal parameters of jqGrid. If the columns will be reordered then the `colNames` array and `colModel` will be reordered too. Thus it's save to use `.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colNames")` and `.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel")`. You will get **the reference** to internal array with the information about the current columns.